# switches- What type of switch is S1 here?

Tags: switches

S1 - Is it just a single push button switch on one side as shown on the symbol, and an open connection on the other side?!

[image]

Comment: I would say it is an open close switch, depending on what you use it for you should check if you need make before break or the other way round

Comment: It's a single-pole double-throw switch. The rest of the circuit diagram is cut off, so we can't tell if the left lead actually connects to anything, but it seems unlikely that there would be a long line drawn going nowhere. The "OPEN-CLOSE" is a description of its function, not what it is. IMO.

Comment: the way it's wired is singe pole double throw equivalent, but it's drawn as having two sets of contact one normally open and the other normally closed.

Comment: You have now completely changed the question to the point that existing answers are out of context.  That's really not nice to the volunteers trying to help.

Comment: Fixing the title and not changing the question is not a complete change. See what they did to op's attempt to ask that as a new question. Rudely closed as a dupe. @Olin

Comment: @Passe: It is a large change because the meaning of the title is now very different.  As someone who answered based on the original title, I feel quite jerked around by the OP.  With 5 downvotes currently, I'm apparently not the only one.  No sympathy from me for how the OP gets treated as a result.  Maybe the whole mess should be closed, if for no other reason than to teach the OP a lesson.  Only 3 more close votes to go.

Answer (score 3):

> S1 - Is it just a single push button switch on one side as shown on the symbol, and an open connection on the other side?!

No. The schematic is oddly drawn  or antiquated. It does look like a normally closed push button on one side and a unconnected connection point or jumper on the other. But that's a standard symbol for a Normally Closed Normally Open, double break push button. It's shape indicates the normally closed pair is on the left. This symbol type is used when a momentary button is intended to be used.

Based on the usage though, with two of the pins connected, it's essentially a spdt switch, and you could use a latching or momentary switch if you want.

Answer (score 1):

The title of the question has been changed to a totally different meaning.  I'm keeping this answer here for reference, since I believe it to be a good answer to the original question.

> How do I put this component (S1) on a PCB?

How you put a component on a PCB depends on it's *package*, not so much its electrical properties.

Get the datasheet of the part and look carefully at the mechanical section.  From that, you figure out where and what size the pads need to be, the diameter of holes (unless all SMD) in the pads, the keepout area for other surrounding parts, etc.

Datasheets often come with recommended footprints.  Often I find they aren't very good.  But, if you don't know where to start, then consider what the datasheet recommends as great and just copy it.

Comment: You can get SPDT switches that are Toggle, and flip back & forth; or SPDT switches that are Momentary, with the default being Open or Closed, depending on how you connect the top leads to the NC and NO pins.  Digikey has a bunch of examples:  https://www.digikey.com/products/en/switches/pushbutton-switches/199?k=tactile

Comment: @Cross: Um, OK, but I don't see why you are telling me, nor how any of that is relevant.  I'm not the one that asked, and the type of available switches has nothing to do with how you put any of them on a board.

Comment: To anyone thinking of down-voting: the original question was "**How do I put this component (S1) on a PCB**", which this answered precisely.

Comment: No, that was only the original title, and this "answer" ignored the body text.

Comment: @Passe: The text wasn't all that clear either.  The title was clear by itself.  I went with the title.  I suppose my real mistake was not quoting the title into the answer so that it was clear what exactly I was answering.  Apparently this isn't what the op *intended* to ask.  I'm not sure why people are downvoting this, since it does answer one of the things the OP asked about, and it is correct.  Note that the question was drastically changed 16 hours *after* this answer was written.

Comment: 6 word  title change to match the question body, and an updated schematic is a dramatic change? The question body hasn't changed. And op tried to ask this as a new question and was met with rules being thrown at him and that closed as a repost/dupe. So what should OP have done?

Comment: @Passe: As I said, the original version was ambiguous.  The title and body were quite different, and the body was a bit confusing or at least out of context.  Picking which one to take as the real question was a tossup.  For anyone looking at the title previously, the new version is dramatically different.  You picked the body originally, and you were right in hindsight.  That doesn't make other original interpretations wrong.  What the OP should have done was written a proper question in the first place instead of jerking around the volunteers.  Maybe this whole mess should be closed now.

Comment: @Passe: I copied the original question into this answer so that at least it is self-consistent.